# Integrating Unit Testing functionality into an old COM-based IDE

Tags: c#, com

My `UnitTesting` add-in works nicely, but it has dependencies on a `Reflection` and a `System` add-in, which means 3 add-ins loaded into Excel to write and run a VBA unit test, and I've recently decided that was a pain in the neck and didn't quite make VBA unit testing, uh, very much *appealing*.

So I proceeded to port my VBA code to C#, and implemented the `Extensibitity.IDTExtensibility2` interface in a new COM-visible class library project.

At this point it only generates a "Test" menu, and so far only two commands have been implemented - I'd like what I have to be reviewed so I can make adjustments before I make a mess implementing the rest of the features.

For visual reference, this is the generated menu:

[image: 'Test' menu, inserted before the 'Window' menu and after the 'Add-Ins' menu on the main menu bar of the VBA IDE.]

At this point, only the "Run/All tests" and "New test module" commands are implemented.

This is the `Extension` class that I've registered with ProgId "RetailCoderVBE" in my registry:

```
using System;
using Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using RetailCoderVBE.VBIDE;
using RetailCoderVBE.UnitTesting;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RetailCoderVBE.UnitTesting.UI;

namespace RetailCoderVBE
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("8D052AD8-BBD2-4C59-8DEC-F697CA1F8A66")]
    [ProgId("RetailCoderVBE")]
    public class Extension : IDTExtensibility2
    {
        private VBE _vbe;
        private TestMenu _testMenu;

        public void OnAddInsUpdate(ref Array custom)
        {
        }

        public void OnBeginShutdown(ref Array custom)
        {
        }

        public void OnConnection(object Application, ext_ConnectMode ConnectMode, object AddInInst, ref Array custom)
        {
            _vbe = (VBE)Application;
        }

        public void OnStartupComplete(ref Array custom)
        {
            CreateTestMenu();
        }

        private void CreateTestMenu()
        {
            if (_vbe == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to initialize add-in.");
            }

            _testMenu = new TestMenu();
            _testMenu.OnNewTestClass += OnNewUnitTestModule;
            _testMenu.OnRunAllTests += OnRunAllTests;

            _testMenu.Initialize(_vbe);
        }

        void OnRunAllTests(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var engine = new TestEngine();
            using (var view = new TestResultsWindow())
            {
                engine.RunAllTests(_vbe, view);
                view.ShowDialog();
            }
        }

        void OnNewUnitTestModule(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NewUnitTestModuleCommand.NewUnitTestModule(_vbe);
        }

        public void OnDisconnection(ext_DisconnectMode RemoveMode, ref Array custom)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The `TestMenu` class encapsulates all the dirty logic that actually generates the menu:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;

namespace RetailCoderVBE.VBIDE
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public class TestMenu
    {
        private CommandBarButton _newTestModuleButton;
        public CommandBarButton NewTestModuleButton { get { return _newTestModuleButton; } }

        private CommandBarButton _runSelectedTestsButton;
        public CommandBarButton RunSelectedTestsButton { get { return _runSelectedTestsButton; } }

        private CommandBarButton _runAllTestsButton;
        public CommandBarButton RunAllTestsButton { get { return _runAllTestsButton; } }

        private CommandBarButton _runFailedTestsButton;
        public CommandBarButton RunFailedTestsButton { get { return _runFailedTestsButton; } }

        private CommandBarButton _runNotRunTestsButton;
        public CommandBarButton RunNotRunTestsButton { get { return _runNotRunTestsButton; } }

        private CommandBarButton _runPassedTestsButton;
        public CommandBarButton RunPassedTestsButton { get { return _runPassedTestsButton; } }

        private CommandBarButton _runRepeatLastRunButton;
        public CommandBarButton RunRepeatLastRunButton { get { return _runRepeatLastRunButton; } }

        private CommandBarButton _windowsTestExplorerButton;
        public CommandBarButton WindowsTestExplorerButton { get { return _windowsTestExplorerButton; } }

        public void Initialize(VBE vbe)
        {
            AddTestMenu(vbe);
        }

        private void AddTestMenu(VBE vbe)
        {
            var menuBarControls = vbe.CommandBars[1].Controls;
            var beforeIndex = FindMenuInsertionIndex(menuBarControls);
            var menu = menuBarControls.Add(Type: MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Before: beforeIndex, Temporary: true) as CommandBarPopup;
            menu.Caption = "Te&st";

            _newTestModuleButton = AddMenuButton(menu);
            _newTestModuleButton.Caption = "&New test module";
            _newTestModuleButton.FaceId = 472; // code module icon
            _newTestModuleButton.Click += OnNewTestModuleButtonClick;

            AddTestRunMenu(menu);
            AddTestWindowsMenu(menu);
        }

        private void AddTestRunMenu(CommandBarPopup menu)
        {
            var runMenu = menu.Controls.Add(Type: MsoControlType.msoControlPopup) as CommandBarPopup;
            runMenu.Caption = "&Run";
            runMenu.BeginGroup = true;

            _runSelectedTestsButton = AddMenuButton(runMenu);
            _runSelectedTestsButton.Caption = "&Selected tests";
            _runSelectedTestsButton.Click += OnRunSelectedTestsButtonClick;

            _runAllTestsButton = AddMenuButton(runMenu);
            _runAllTestsButton.Caption = "&All tests";
            _runAllTestsButton.FaceId = 186; // a "play" icon
            _runAllTestsButton.Click += OnRunAllTestsButtonClick;

            _runFailedTestsButton = AddMenuButton(runMenu);
            _runFailedTestsButton.Caption = "&Failed tests";
            _runFailedTestsButton.Click += OnRunFailedTestsButtonClick;

            _runNotRunTestsButton = AddMenuButton(runMenu);
            _runNotRunTestsButton.Caption = "&Not run tests";
            _runNotRunTestsButton.Click += OnRunNotRunTestsButtonClick;

            _runPassedTestsButton = AddMenuButton(runMenu);
            _runPassedTestsButton.Caption = "&Passed tests";
            _runPassedTestsButton.Click += OnRunPassedTestsButtonClick;

            _runRepeatLastRunButton = AddMenuButton(runMenu);
            _runRepeatLastRunButton.Caption = "Repeat &last run";
            _runRepeatLastRunButton.Click += OnRepeatLastRunButtonClick;
        }

        private void AddTestWindowsMenu(CommandBarPopup menu)
        {
            _windowsTestExplorerButton = AddMenuButton(menu);
            _windowsTestExplorerButton.Caption = "&Test Explorer";
            _windowsTestExplorerButton.BeginGroup = true;
            _windowsTestExplorerButton.FaceId = 305; // a "document" icon, with a green checkmark and a red cross
            _windowsTestExplorerButton.Click += OnTestExplorerButtonClick;
        }

        private int FindMenuInsertionIndex(CommandBarControls controls)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= controls.Count; i++)
            {
                // insert menu before "Window" built-in menu:
                if (controls[i].BuiltIn && controls[i].Caption == "&Window")
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }

            return controls.Count;
        }

        private CommandBarButton AddMenuButton(CommandBarPopup menu)
        {
            return menu.Controls.Add(Type: MsoControlType.msoControlButton) as CommandBarButton;
        }

        public event EventHandler OnNewTestClass;
        void OnNewTestModuleButtonClick(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
        {
            var handler = OnNewTestClass;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler OnRunSelectedTests;
        void OnRunSelectedTestsButtonClick(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
        {
            var handler = OnRunSelectedTests;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler OnRunAllTests;
        void OnRunAllTestsButtonClick(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
        {
            var handler = OnRunAllTests;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler OnRunFailedTests;
        void OnRunFailedTestsButtonClick(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
        {
            var handler = OnRunFailedTests;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler OnRunNotRunTests;
        void OnRunNotRunTestsButtonClick(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
        {
            var handler = OnRunNotRunTests;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler OnRunPassedTests;
        void OnRunPassedTestsButtonClick(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
        {
            var handler = OnRunPassedTests;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler OnRepeatLastRun;
        void OnRepeatLastRunButtonClick(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
        {
            var handler = OnRepeatLastRun;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler OnTestExporer;
        void OnTestExplorerButtonClick(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
        {
            var handler = OnTestExporer;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you've noticed, the `OnRunAllTests` method in the `Extension` class is implemented directly in the `Extension` class. It's short, trivial. But it feels like breaking SRP.

On the other hand, I have this `NewUnitTestModuleCommand` class, that makes the `OnNewUnitTestModule` handler a one-liner:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using RetailCoderVBE.Reflection;

namespace RetailCoderVBE.UnitTesting
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    internal static class NewUnitTestModuleCommand
    {
        private static readonly string TestModuleTemplate = string.Concat(
            "Option Explicit\n",
            "Private Assert As New RetailCoderVBE.AssertClass\n\n",
            "'test explorer searches in standard code modules, for all\n",
            "'public parameterless procedures with a name that starts with \"Test\".\n",
            "Public Sub TestMethod1()\n",
            "    Assert.Inconclusive\n",
            "End Sub\n\n",
            "'...or public parameterless procedures with a @TestMethod marker:\n",
            "'@TestMethod\n",
            "Public Sub TestMethod2()\n",
            "    Assert.Inconclusive\n",
            "End Sub\n\n",
            "'test methods that raise an error will result in an inconclusive test:\n",
            "'@TestMethod\n",
            "Public Sub TestMethod3()\n",
            "    Err.Raise 5\n",
            "End Sub\n\n"
            );

        private static readonly string TestModuleBaseName = "TestModule";

        public static void NewUnitTestModule(VBE vbe)
        {
            var project = vbe.ActiveVBProject;
            Project.EnsureProjectHasReferenceToAddInTypeLib(project);

            var module = project.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
            module.Name = GetNextTestModuleName(project);
            module.CodeModule.AddFromString(TestModuleTemplate);
            module.Activate();
        }

        private static string GetNextTestModuleName(VBProject project)
        {
            var names = Project.GetComponentNames(project);
            var index = names.Count(n => n.StartsWith(TestModuleBaseName)) + 1;

            return string.Concat(TestModuleBaseName, index);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like that it's `static`. In fact I feel like I've overused `static` classes in this project, and I'd like it to be more... *object-oriented*.

This is the code-behind for the form I'm using to display the test results:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RetailCoderVBE.UnitTesting.UI
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public partial class TestResultsWindow : Form, ITestOutput
    {
        public TestResultsWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void WriteResult(string projectName, string testName, TestResult result)
        {
            testOutputGridView.Rows.Add(projectName, testName, result.Outcome.ToString(), result.Output, result.Duration.ToString() + " ms");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: test module template results]

Here's the `TestEngine` class where I'm going to be implementing all the "Run" commands into:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using RetailCoderVBE.Reflection;

namespace RetailCoderVBE.UnitTesting
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ITestOutput
    {
        void WriteResult(string projectName, string testName, TestResult result);
    }

    [ComVisible(false)]
    internal class TestEngine
    {
        public void RunAllTests(VBE vbe, ITestOutput output)
        {
            var projects = vbe.VBProjects.Cast<VBProject>();
            var tests = new List<TestMethod>();
            foreach (var project in projects)
            {
                tests.AddRange(FindTestMethods(project));
            }

            foreach (var test in tests)
            {
                var result = test.Run();
                output.WriteResult(test.ProjectName, test.MethodName, result);
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<TestMethod> FindTestMethods(VBProject project)
        {
            var modules = project.VBComponents
                                 .Cast<VBComponent>()
                                 .Where(component => component.Type == vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
            foreach (var module in modules)
            {
                var publicProcedures = ProjectComponent.GetMembers(module.CodeModule)
                                                       .Where(member => member.MemberType == MemberType.Sub 
                                                                     && member.MemberVisibility == MemberVisibility.Public
                                                                     && member.Signature.EndsWith(member.Name + "()"));

                foreach (var procedure in publicProcedures)
                {
                    if (!procedure.HasAttribute<TestMethodAttribute>() && !procedure.Name.StartsWith("Test"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    yield return new TestMethod(project.Name, procedure.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks pretty good. A few minors:

1. You repeat a lot of code for the event raising. An extension method could help to facilitate DRY:

   ```
   static public void Raise(this EventHandler handler, object sender)
   {
       if (handler != null)
       {
           handler(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
       }
   }
   ```

   then you can raise an event like this:

   ```
   OnNewTestClass.Raise(this);
   ```
2. In `FindTestMethods` you find a set of methods with LINQ yet in the loop you still have this check:

   > ```
   > if (!procedure.HasAttribute<TestMethodAttribute>() && !procedure.Name.StartsWith("Test"))
   > {
   >     continue;
   > }
   > ```

   which you could pull up into the `Where` clause as well. I'd also extract the `Where` condition into a private method like `IsTestMethod` and utilize `SelectMany` to get all members of all components. With all of that the method can be refactored to:

   ```
   private IEnumerable<TestMethod> FindTestMethods(VBProject project)
   {
       return project.VBComponents
                     .Cast<VBComponent>()
                     .Where(component => component.Type == vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule)
                     .SelectMany(module => ProjectComponent.GetMembers(module.CodeModule))
                     .Where(IsTestMethod)
                     .Select(procedure => new TestMethod(project.Name, procedure.Name));
   }
   ```